# How to unit test a presenter that spawns another view without a GUI appearing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mvp

I have a presenter class that will spawn a new presenter and view upon successful execution. Prior to spawning the next presenter/view, some business logic executes that I wish to unit test. My issue is that I cannot avoid an actual GUI window appearing when my unit test executes.

Here is some psuedo-code that demonstrates the issue:

```
// View1 and Model are interfaces
public Presenter1(View1 view, Model model) {
  // ....
}


public void handleOKClick() {
  // Method triggered by view

  String data = view.getSomeUserInput();
  // ... business logic I wish to test  


  if (shouldLoadNextView) {
    // Business logic concluded the next view should be loaded

    View2 nextView = new View2Impl();
    Presenter2 nextPresenter = new Presenter2(nextView, model);
    nextView.setPresenter(nextPresenter);
    nextView.showView();
  }
}
```

In my unit test, I can mock the `View1` and `Model` instances that I pass to my `Presenter1` constructor. I can then check that my business logic interacts with these as expected. What I can't currently do is prevent the next view from displaying, as my `Presenter1` instance will construct a concrete implementation of `View2` and display it.

I feel like I'm left with three choices:

1. Change the design of my class. Perhaps the `Presenter1` constructor should take a `View2` instance as an argument, allowing me to mock it for the purposes of testing.
2. Find a cunning way to kill the view from my unit test code, once it has appeared. I'm not sure how best to do this.
3. Make a more fundamental change to my project class design so that presenters never spawn new views in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time has passed and I've since adopted option 1. It feels clunky to pre-construct views when they may not be needed, but equally my view classes are lightweight and cheap to construct.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you i would go for option 3, make your presenter communicate through events with other view so you can keep them loosly coupled and the presenter would become easier to test and simpler to implement.

Comment: Suggesting events as an alternative communication method doesn't address the issue of how the other views would be instantiated.